# How to Divide an A3 html document onto two A4

Tags: html, css

i'm newbie to html, i want to create html page in A3 mode, i have download this code from github [A3.HTML](https://github.com/cognitom/paper-css/blob/master/examples/a3-landscape.html) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>A3 landscape</title>

  <!-- Normalize or reset CSS with your favorite library -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/7.0.0/normalize.min.css">

  <!-- Load paper.css for happy printing -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper-css/0.4.1/paper.css">

  <!-- Set page size here: A5, A4 or A3 -->
  <!-- Set also "landscape" if you need -->
  <style>@page { size: A3 landscape }</style>
</head>

<!-- Set "A5", "A4" or "A3" for class name -->
<!-- Set also "landscape" if you need -->
<body class="A3 landscape">

  <!-- Each sheet element should have the class "sheet" -->
  <!-- "padding-**mm" is optional: you can set 10, 15, 20 or 25 -->
  <section class="sheet padding-10mm">

    <!-- Write HTML just like a web page -->
    <article>This is an A3 document (landscape).</article>

  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Now i want to divide my A3 in two A4 ( like opening a book, left page and right page ),[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVzsx.png)

i want to be able to write in the left page and the right one, can someone help me ? Thanks :)